# Matlab code to C using Matlab coder

Tags: c, matlab, visual-c++, matlab-coder

I have some working Matlab code, which I try to transform into C code using the Matlab coder. I am getting this error:

```
18   c:\users\bla\project\strcmpi.h(79) : warning C4028: formal parameter 2 different from declaration
19   c:\users\bla\project\strcmpi.h(79) : error C2371: 'strcmpi' : redefinition; different basic types
20           c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(245) : see declaration of 'strcmpi'
21   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
22   Stop.
23   The make command returned an error of 2
24   'An_error_occurred_during_the_call_to_make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
25   operable program or batch file.
```

It looks very C specific to me (I am not a proficient C programmer). Can anyone please point me in the right direction to overcome this error? Thanks.

PS:

Here is some adapted Matlab code:

```
if(strcmpi(parameters.x,'bladibla') == 1)

    % some code

else

    % some more code

end
```

where 'parameters' is a struct. I would like to stick to my struct but if there are better ways to achieve the above, especially in the context of the Matlab coder and C, please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the 'strcmpi' function in your Matlab code with coder.ceval or something? Including the relevant parts of your code would help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have added some Matlab code (see PS:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about strcmpi() (case-insensitive string comparison) is that it's not a standard C function. Thus, code that relies on it but tries to be portable across platforms sometimes has to provide its own implementation while deferring to the system's implementation if available. In my experience, the project's own strcmpi() implementation will be protected by a configuration option. If you open up c:\users\bla\project\strcmpi.h, you might see code similar to this:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_STRCMPI_PRESENT
int strcmpi(const char *string1, const char *string2);
#endif  // CONFIG_STRCMPI_PRESENT
```

If you see this, the trick to getting around the problem will probably be to find the associated config.h file and uncomment the following line:

```
// #define CONFIG_STRCMPI_PRESENT
```

This is all just a guess based on my experience with similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added some Matlab code (see PS:).

Comment: The high-level usage of strcmpi() wouldn't be the problem. The problem is that there are 2 different definitions of strcmpi() floating around the codebase. To solve this problem, you will need to eliminate one of those strcmpi() implementations, and it will probably be the one built into the project (rather than the system version).